# help improving vast search interface

Tags: search, advancedsearch

A search engine is used by document controllers to search for documents, types of documents, locations that contain documents. The documents are described by vast amounts of meta data and the search interface looks like this:

[image]

The tabs at the top either scope the search (tasks, documents) or manage previously run searches (...Manager)
The folder system to the left appears to do nothing.

I have been given no research information so have no rationale for any of the decisions that  created the interface.

I can simplify this interface by:

- getting rid of the tabs at the top and creating one unified view
- tidying up the alignment of fields and labels
- getting rid of rarely used fields
- grouping or combining similar fields
- creating a simple search
- splitting the right hand frame into two so that results are visible with criteria

But what else could I consider? What about a filter results panel? Am I missing something?

Edit

I would love to do research but no client go-ahead for that

edit 2

here's my solution
[image]

still waiting to get go ahead for research

problem: if the user chooses different meta data from the filters, the column tables wont make sense. How do I get round this?

Comment: You don't even know how to use the application and you have decided you need to simplify?  Learn the application as it is and talk to users.  What is your basis to get rid of rarely used fields?  The fire extinguisher in the hall is rarely used.  I see nothing wrong with that alignment.

Comment: There are many potential fundamental UX issues to be addressed from looking at the screenshot.

PS fire extinguisher argument does not logically follow

Comment: You say "I would love to do research but no client go-ahead for that" - but what **do** you have go-ahead for? Has the client requested a redesign, or is this part of a system-wide set of improvements, or is this a one-off idea to change this particular screen?

Comment: Heuristic review for large software app and I'm saying that's all well and good but I need to talk to end users if I'm to make it really useful. Every seasoned UX pro reading this will share my frustration.

Comment: Seasoned UX pros may share your frustration; but that will be nothing compared to the fury of your users if you remove their valued functionality without being really, **really** sure of what you're doing. Personally, I'd refuse to touch it until you get to do your research.

Comment: I have pitched in.  What part of leave it alone is not clear?  You clearly have no subject matter expertise and you don't have access to users.  About that langue - I hope you conduct your business in a more professional manner.  Really you think keyword replaces version, lock and all those fields you chopped.  Why would I want search and results on the same screen?  I run the search and then I view the results.  I don't want to share space.

Comment: Then lets re-frame the debate. Be constructive: as a domain expert, how would you improve the original layout?

Comment: You are looking at this as a "consumer application" and trying to assign those UX standards.  A document controller is a very specific task and control points like version and lock are essential to the task.  If you looked at tool like SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) you would see stuff that is catered to that task and does not have consumer look.  In medicine they have a term do no harm. I am sorry you don't have access to the users but you need to tell them it is just plain a requirement.

Comment: Since I don't know the the target user I cannot make suggestion as there a class of users I think the current design is perfect for.  If they are trying to take specific document control app and turn it into a general consumer level document management tool then I get some of your changes.  There needs to be a target user or users you access to.

Comment: you're an end user, a doc controller!So you are actually the kind of person i need to talk to. So forget my wireframes and lets focus on the original design. Do you, personally, as an ex doc controller, find that interface to your liking? If not, would you be prepared to come up with a few suggestions as to how you would improve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17295/discussion-between-blam-and-colmcq).

Answer (score 1):

If it meets the requirements, you probably should consider an initial/normal search that shows the users far fewer fields and then provide an advanced search option that repaints the screen.

Is the tree view on the left the filter or is it part of the search criteria (like selecting a folder in Windows Explorer and then searching in the right pane for items in that folder)? And I agree with you about dropping the tabs. Also, consider placing the label to the right of the check box control and use the same capitalization style for all controls.

Comment: the folders on the left scope the search to just that folder unless the user over rides it with the Search drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got a handle on this. Applying the suggestions you've made will result in a clearer UI.

In answer to your question, I'd say that what's missing here is some user research. You say that you've "been given no research information". Does that mean that you can't get any of your own? One of the mantras of this site and industry is that you should be making design decisions in the context of your users' goals.

How often and in what way features are actually used should determine their prominence in the UI. Making your changes based on information gleaned from a few observation/interview sessions will result in a better first draft than in if design based on your own assumptions (even if you're a user)

Comment: " I'd say that what's missing here is some user research. " this is what I say everyday to folks that work here. They are slowly getting it. User research is the key to all of UX

Answer (score 1):

You could group many rarely-used search rules into a single drop-down.  When one of these rules is selected, it then gives you the options for that rule and allows you to add it as a rule to the search.

Another idea to consider is to use keywords in the search string.  For example, if you type `to:email@address`, GMail will only search for emails to that address.  This may be helpful if the users of this search interface tend to use it a lot. 
A drop down of rules as suggested above would work well in conjunction with this--selecting a rule would cause the appropriate keyword and values for that rule to be added to the search string.

Answer (score 1):

You should do some user research. I think (but this is an assumption), that the fields could be better organized then.

Look at which fields are mostly used, put them on top, provide advanced search, and then group fields based on how often they are used together.

But, like I said, do some user research.